# Is there a way to select a random number from two different ranges at once?

Tags: python

So, basically, I have two ranges. "Narrow range" is any number from -0.5 to 0.3 (up to 5 decimal places), and the "Full range" is any number from -1 to 1.
To select a random value, for each, I do the following:

```
 narrowrange=np.random.uniform(-.5,.3)
 fullrange=np.random.uniform(-1,1)
```

However, I would like to create a new range, which subtracts the narrowrange from the fullrange. In other words, I'd like to select random numbers from -1 to -0.5 and 0.3 to 1 (so excluding any numbers from the narrow range).

The only way I can think of doing this is by creating an if statement for the full range (if this generated # falls into the narrow range, then generate a # again). Anyone know how to do this without for loops/if statements?

Comment: You could generate a number between 0 and 1.2 (0.5 + 0.7) - and check if that number is below 0.5, in which case subtract 1, otherwise subtract 0.2. Basically you need to calculate the actual range of random numbers you want (1.2) and then move the output into the original ranges.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.random.choice` with a list of `random.uniform` as parameter

```
np.random.choice([np.random.uniform(-1, -.5), np.random.uniform(.3, 1)])
```

If you would like to add weight as suggested in the comments you can use the `p` parameter

```
total = -.5 + 1 + 1 - .3
p = [(-.5 + 1) / total, (1 - .3) / total]
np.random.choice([np.random.uniform(-1, -.5), np.random.uniform(.3, 1)], p=p)
```

Comment: This is incorrect, unless both intervals have the same width. You'd have to provide weights of the inverse of the width

Comment: For instance try: `np.random.choice([np.random.uniform(0, 0.001), np.random.uniform(1, 1001)])`, this gives a 1:1 chance to get a number from either interval while the ratio should be 1:1000000

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of how to do it without an if statement, but I can do it without the risk of multiple tries.

Your full range of values is 1.2 (-1 to -0.5 is a range of 0.5, and 0.3 to 1 is a range of 0.7, so that's 1.2 in total).

I would suggest picking a random number in the range 1.2, and then shifting that value into one of the two ranges based on where it lies:

```
unshifted = np.random.uniform(0, 1.2)
if unshifted <= 0.5:
    shifted = unshifted - 1
else:
    shifted = unshifted - 0.2
```